# SurveyMonkey Long Lived Access Token Lifespan

Tags: oauth-2.0, survey, surveymonkey

I am working on a project that requires an automated SSIS package to
connect to SurveyMonkey data store via API to incrementally download survey
results for the day or specified time period for custom reporting and low scoring task assignment.

Via OAuth I can collect a long lived access token, but due to the automated
and infinite nature of my projects lifespan, I cannot manually initiate
OAuth2 token refreshes or complete manual re-authentication cycles.

Is there another method to automatically export this data upon a scheduled
request?

Additionally, for clarification for how long is a long lived access token
valid? 60 days?

Answer (score 5):

Miles from surveymonkey.com support responded to me with a great answer.  I hope it can help someone down the line.

> Hi Rob,
>
> Currently our tokens should not expire - this is not guaranteed and
>   may change in future, but we will send out an update well ahead of
>   time if this does ever change.  The token you receive on completion of
>   OAuth lets you know how long the token will last for without user
>   intervention, currently it returns 'null' in the 'expires_in' field.
>
> There is no other automated way to schedule the data to be exported
>   currently, however it sounds like our current setup should suit your
>   needs

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Miles's reply,  it is very straightforward to pull diffs from surveymonkey using modified dates.   we keep "last sync" timestamp per-survey in our database,  and update it after each successful data pull.
Use the REST api directly,  or (*if you're using PHP*) try https://github.com/oori/php-surveymonkey.   We run it in production.

*note:   actually, you're interested in setting the **start_modified_date** option for the "**getRespondentList**" function.    but in general - see the API docs, modified date filter is available in more functions.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the OP's question.